# numpyの情報落ちを防ぐ方法はありますでしょうか？

Tags: python, numpy

numpyの情報落ちを防ぐ方法はありますでしょうか？
例えば、下記のコードであれば
[0.000000000000000000001486436280241437]
[-0.999999999999999999998514...]
といった出力を期待しているのですが、
結果的に2行目のprintは
[-1.]
となってしまいます。

情報落ちを防ぐ方法を探しているのですが、何か良い方法はありますでしょうか。

```
import numpy as np
print(np.power(np.array([10.0]) + 1, -20))
print(np.power(np.array([10.0]) + 1, -20) - 1)
```

【質問の背景】
sklearn.preprocessing.PowerTransformerを使用して、Yeo-Johnson変換を実行しているのですが
transformモジュールの中で下記の処理を実行しているようです。
ここの処理で情報落ちが発生してエラーとなっている状態です。

```
(np.power(x[pos] + 1, lmbda) - 1) / lmbda
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Decimal` 型にするとよいかもしれません。ただし、元の `numpy.float64` 型での計算と比較すると実行速度は落ちると思われます。

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
>>> arr = np.power(np.array([10.0]) + 1, -20)
>>> arr.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>>
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> arr = np.vectorize(Decimal.from_float)(arr)
>>> arr
array([Decimal('1.48643628024143692488090018058568364159624895579727024715987852843124272794739226810634136199951171875E-21')],
      dtype=object)
>>> arr.dtype
dtype('O')
>>>
>>> arr - 1
array([Decimal('-0.9999999999999999999985135637')], dtype=object)
```

Comment: 頂いた情報を元に解決できそうです。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

Decimal を使うとか？

```
from decimal import *
import numpy as np

print(np.power(np.array([Decimal(10.0)]) + 1, -20))
print(np.power(np.array([Decimal(10.0)]) + 1, -20) - 1)
```

Comment: 頂いた情報を元に解決できそうです。ありがとうございました。